# Ensure format CRLF if not present

Tags: perl, newline

I have a script, MM.pl, which is the “workhorse”, and a simple “.patch” that it reads from. It targets an original text file from a 2004 program usually a text file of the .txt or .ini extention.It searches the target file for the "old" data from the patch file and if found substitutes it with the "new" data from the patch file. To find the problem I have programmed the pl to hexdump the old and new data and the target file. Viola! The target file is formatted with CRLF and the patch file old and new only contain LF. I need a solution that will ensure the patch file old/new data contains the CRLF format. This is used by Mac and windows users and the patch file can be generated by any text editor. Thats why I need it to check and correct the EOL format to ensure comapatability with the CRLF format.

Comment: Lots of line ending scripts kicking about the internet - http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=8991

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=890769 look for :crlf layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to replace single `\n` with `\r\n`.
I don't have a Perl interpreter at hand, but something like this should work:

```
$string =~ s/!\r\n/\r\n/g;
```

Comment: Lost my hard drive and had to start over with everything. Switched to python since I lost the original Perl program.